# How to display Office add-in's title in one line

Tags: office-js

I am following this article to setup my add-in manifest: [Office Add-ins XML manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests). I would like to display the title of the buttons in one line. How can I control line-break in the Office add-in manifest?

The following is the code snippet I am using:

[image]

And this is result displaying by the host app:

[image]

But in Office ribbon,it is OK.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot control or set line-breaks through Office manifest file. This is comes from Office ribbon implementation which is not allow to control word wrapping and line breaks of the title.

If this is something you would like to see in upcoming Office.js releases I would suggest to post your business case at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: But in Office ribbon.line-breaks does work. for example,```label=" 登录 &#13;" ```

Comment: In your example what are you breaking? added `&#13` to the end of the title will not do anything and will be ignored. Adding the same in the middle will not break the title as well `登&#13;录`.